# Check if element is fully scrolled

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mouseevent

I have following markup structure.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

Now, class `content-wrapper` is set to have only `80%` height of total client-area of page, and has `overflow-y` set to `auto` to have a scrollbar when its body doesn't fit in. Note that the inner divs `content` can be for any number of times. So, question is **how can I check if `content-wrapper` is fully scrolled?**

#### Hint:

Imagine a dynamically loading news feed, where new content is fetched and appended to body of container automatically when container is fully scrolled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var isFullyScrolled = this.scrollTop + this.clientHeight >= this.scrollHeight;
```

Also I would've subtract a few pixels from scroll height for case with some fractions.

```js
document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var isFullyScrolled = this.scrollTop + this.clientHeight >= this.scrollHeight;
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = isFullyScrolled;
});
```

```css
html, body, section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  height: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: silver;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<output>Scroll</output>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to determine if the element is fully scrolled on its **width** (The x-axis), here is how:

```
const scrolledElement = document.getElementById(ELEMENT_ID);
const isElementFullyScrolled = scrolledElement.scrollWidth - scrolledElement.scrollLeft === scrolledElement.clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and add a div on the end with no content, just give it some height. And check if that div is in viewport. If it is it means that you reached the end of the scroll. Here is a great jQuery plugin for checking if element is in view. http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var top = $('.content-wrapper').scrollTop();
var height = $('.content-wrapper').height();
if(top==height) {
//load more data
}
```

Comment: Not helping. :/ note that number and size of inner `content` divs varies.

Comment: Then post some fiddle for it to play around.